# Converting datatable into xml with a unique id row

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, datatable

I am converting datatable into xml.

```
DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet("Products");
products.TableName = "Product";
dataSet1.Tables.Add(products);
dataSet1.WriteXml(directory + "//matrix.xml");
```

The code is working fine. I just want to add a unique id column in each row. How can i do this?. Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why dont you have such a column right in the data table?

Comment: do you mean to add unique id in each datarow?

Comment: Yes. This approach will allow you to keep your xml data linked with the database in a clear and straightforward manner, which is always useful.

Comment: can you tell me how can i add into the datarow? i want a unique id in each datarow. i could not find on google. Sorry i am new to programming

Comment: This depends on the database engine you're using. Please post `CREATE` script of your table alongside with the database engine name/version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to, create a *new* column defining uniqueness on your table and then export to `Xml`

```
var column = new DataColumn("UniqueRow", typeof(System.String));    
products.Columns.Add(column );
column.SetOrdinal(0); // first column 

foreach(DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
{
    row[column] = Guid.NewGuid(); // or any other id 
}
```

Now you can use same code to export to Xml.

```
DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet("Products");
products.TableName = "Product";
dataSet1.Tables.Add(products);
dataSet1.WriteXml(directory + "//matrix.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks @Hari this is exactly what i was looking for. Can i move the UniqueRow at the top right now it is at the bottom

Comment: I'm glad, it helped.

Comment: how can i move the row at the top

Comment: You can simply set  `column.SetOrdinal(0);`

Comment: @OwaisAhmed  If it worked to you, please upvote and mark as accepted. It help others having similar issue/problem.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
products.column.add("uniqueID");
products.acceptchanges();

for each(datarow dr in products)
{
  int counter = 1
  dr["uniqueID"].Value = counter;
  counter++;
}
```